# messaging between applications in cluster

Tags: c#, protocols, cluster-computing

I want to know protocols about messaging between cluster-awake applications in cluster.
My programming language is `C#`.

Comment: What do you want to know? Be specific. And what have you tried?

Comment: @SamuelSlade Some thing like when an application end send messages to other cluster-awake applications and...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try queue messaging with Msmq for example.